# Why does enqueueing OpenCL kernels for execution cause a program's memory use to increase?

Tags: memory, asynchronous, opencl

I'm running a simulation on all cores of an Intel CPU using OpenCL. The main process code consists of a loop within which repeated calls to opencl kernels are made. No memory gets allocated inside the loop and no events are used. However, the program's memory usage steadily increases in the course of the simulation unless I add periodic calls to `clFinish()` and `clFlush()`.

Can anyone explain what's going on here?

Comment: Are you getting events returned from any of your calls? If so, you are responsible for releasing them.

Comment: Thanks! But I'm not using any events.

Comment: If you enqueue OpenCL calls in a loop (suppose 1000000x queues of a kernel) in a non blocking way. Then these queues have to be stored somehere. That eats memory until you `clflush()` to GPU, or wait for it to `clFinish()`. However it should not grow indefinitely since the driver should take care of it at some point. That's my best guess.

Comment: I agree with DarkZeros. Before you edited, it used to say you used blocking calls (I assume read/write buffer or image) which should have also prevented queue growth. But if you're not, then you should clFinish/clFlush from time to time, or use events to ensure you don't queue too far ahead.

Comment: You're right. The situation I found the "leak" in was a case where the blocking mem copy commands were omitted. When I realised this I edited the question. @DarkZeros, if you post your comment as an answer I'll accept it. Thank you both very much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it was the answer to the question I put it here:

If you enqueue OpenCL calls in a loop in a non blocking way. Then these call queues have to be stored somewhere. That eats memory until you `clflush()` to GPU, or wait for it to `clFinish()`. However it should not grow indefinitely since the driver should take care of it at some point.

Comment: Not indefinitely, but whatever way Intel is storing these things doesn't seem hugely efficient :) It eat up 8 gb of ram and a good chunk of swap before I was able to halt it.

Comment: There's nothing in the specification saying it won't grow indefinitely, nor have I seen any vendor do this. I think the OPs evidence points to at least one driver that doesn't cap the size of the host-side queue. An easy solution is to call clFinish every N jobs you've queued. If you are really worried about never letting the queue be empty, then use a fixed number of Events with your kernels and only queue up a new one after the oldest one has finished.